Auto Login with GDM3 nonstop starts indefinite new user sessions in Ubuntu 22.04
i want my VPS, running with Ubuntu 22.04 automatically login into my user account and start an Ubuntu desktop session. This is especially important after unplanned reboots of the VPS, but the problem is, that not only one, but nonstop new user sessions are created upon boot. I want only one user session.


Is your "user account" root?

Thank you very much for your comment. Yes, i tried it with "root", after having tried with a "normal" user account. The result is always the same. Do you know how it can be fixed?
